# migrating openshift 2 application to openshift 3

Tags: migration, openshift

I'm unable to migrate an application from OpenShift2 to OpenShift3.
I've an instance of Fuseki installed on Openshift2. It is viewed as being on a 'redHat type' account. 
It uses a cartridge of type "Do-It-Yourself 0.1"
I'm able to copy the content in a local git by using ssh link at the right of my config page.
Then, I created a new account in Openshift3 and I don't see any documentation or tool useful to install my application on OpenShift3.
The migration must be done before the end of the month and I'm stuck at that point.
Any help?

Comment: this may be helpful: https://blog.openshift.com/migrating-your-applications-from-openshift-2-to-3/

Comment: Consider starting out by reading the free eBook at https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html and work through exercises at https://learn.openshift.com That will give you a better understanding of how OpenShift 3 works. You can also find various blog posts at https://blog.openshift.com

Comment: Put my application on OpenShift2 was well documented, straightforward and quick. I understand that migrate it to Openshift3 will be far longer, complex and I doubt I will find the time to learn and understand how to do it before Sepetember, 30. Really bad

Comment: ricka: before my message on SO, I take some time to read all that I've found like  blog.openshift.com/. It's not really straightforward. For exemple, under the the Git Hosting section, I read "choose your build configuration" and I've no build configuration, so I need to find where is documented the creation of a build configuration, what type of build configuration I need, build it and validate it and it seems to be just a step in the journey!